# ¿Cómo crear un array que contenga productos con una misma ID en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

ando creando un carrito con arreglos y sesiones pero tengo un problema, lo que pasas es qué a la hora de ingresar los productos al carrito este los hace de forma correcta, pero cuándo quiero ingresar un mismo producto EJ: si pido una BUJÍA con ID=1 y lo agrego al carrito; y después agrego otra BUJÍA con ID=1; no quiero que me añada 1+ en cantidad(esto es lo que actualmente me está haciendo), aquí les mostraré lo que actualmente me imprime:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si yo agrego otro producto con ID=1 me sumará la cantidad de 1 a 2, anexo imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué quiero hacer?... qué en vez de añadirme 1+ a la cantidad, me cree otro array cómo lo muestra el primero, pero que lleve la misma ID=1 ya que con esa ID iré actualizando el stock en mi inventario para llevar un orden, *estaba pensando en crear otro array pero y sí ingresan muchísimos productos que van con esa misma ID=1 son muchos arrays por recorrer y sería un martirio :(... a no ser que me den ideas o bases para comenzar a codificar* espero y me puedan ayudar anexo mi código fuente de lo que llevo y espero me puedan ayudar...

index.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
/*include ('./php/conexion.php');*/
$_GET['id_producto'] = 1;
if (isset($_SESSION['carrito_venta'])){
    //si existe buscamos si ya estaba agregado ese producto
  if (isset($_GET['id_producto'])){
    $arreglo = $_SESSION['carrito_venta'];
    $encontro = false;
    $numero = 0;
    for ($i=0;$i<count($arreglo);$i++){
      if ($arreglo[$i]['Id'] == $_GET['id_producto']){
        $encontro = true;
        $numero=$i;
      }
    }
    if ($encontro == true){
      /*Si encuentra un registro con la misma ID me le añade 1+ a la cantidad y aquí es dónde quiero modificar el código para hacer lo que quiero...*/
      $arreglo[$numero]['Cantidad']=$arreglo[$numero]['Cantidad']+1;
      $_SESSION['carrito_venta']=$arreglo;
    }else{
            //No estaba el registro
      $tipo = "";
      $nombre = "";
      $descripcion = "";
      /*$res = $conexion->query('SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id='.$_GET['id_producto'])or die($conexion->error);*/
      /*$fila = mysqli_fetch_row($res);*/
      $tipo = "Productos";
      $nombre = "DD111018";
      $descripcion = "BUJIA CHAMPION P-RZ9HC/BOXER K-TEC/PULSAR 135 LS DD111018";
      $arregloNuevo = array(
        'Id' => $_GET['id_producto'],
        'Tipo' => $tipo,
        'Nombre' => $nombre,
        'Descripcion' => $descripcion,
        'Bodega' => 'Sin asignar',
        'Cantidad' => 1,
        'ValorUnitario' => 0,
        'Descuento' => 0,
        'Total' => 0
      );
      array_push($arreglo, $arregloNuevo);
      $_SESSION['carrito_venta']=$arreglo;
    }
  }
}else{
    //creamos la variable de sesion
  if (isset($_GET['id_producto'])){
    $tipo = "";
    $nombre = "";
    $descripcion = "";
    /*$res = $conexion->query('SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id='.$_GET['id_producto'])or die($conexion->error);*/
    /*$fila = mysqli_fetch_row($res);*/
    $tipo = "Productos";
    $nombre = "DD111018";
    $descripcion = "BUJIA CHAMPION P-RZ9HC/BOXER K-TEC/PULSAR 135 LS DD111018";
    $arreglo[] = array(
      'Id' => $_GET['id_producto'],
      'Tipo' => $tipo,
      'Nombre' => $nombre,
      'Descripcion' => $descripcion,
      'Bodega' => 'Sin asignar',
      'Cantidad' => 1,
      'ValorUnitario' => 0,
      'Descuento' => 0,
      'Total' => 0
    );
    $_SESSION['carrito_venta']=$arreglo;
  }
}
?>
```

productos_venta.php -> dónde muestro mi array:

```
<?php 
session_start();
/*Productos sin repetir*/
print_r($_SESSION['carrito_venta']);

?>
```

Comment: Disculpa la curiosidad pero ¿de quién es el código? ¿Te has tomado el tiempo de leer los comentarios que tiene? Creo que la respuesta que buscas lo vas a poder obtener si le dedicas unos minutos a entender que es lo que se hace en `index.php`

Comment: Hola marco, la verdad ese código lo saqué de internet y tendré en cuenta lo que me dices :)